# Limit of this sequence.

Tags: limits

Let a sequence be defined as $f(n+1)=\frac{1}{2}[f(n)+\frac{9}{f(n)}]$ where $n\in \mathbb{N},\forall n f(n)>0$. What limit does the sequence tend to as n→∞? I tried to do this by by observing that the minimum value of the RHS expression is 6, so minimum value of $f(n)$ should be 3. But these are just minimum values, and I have no idea about the limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is an strictly increasing function, then
$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(n) = \displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(n+1) = L$$

So 
$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(n+1) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2}\left[f(n)+\frac{9}{f(n)}\right]\Rightarrow L = \frac{1}{2}\left[L+\frac{9}{L}\right]$$
where $L>0$.

Comment: How do you know that f(n) is increasing?

Answer (score 1):

Let me point that the sequence $(u_n)_{n\ge 0}$, recursively defined by 
$$u_{n+1}=\dfrac12\Bigl(u_n+\dfrac a{u_n}\Bigr)$$
is known to be the basis of the algorithm implemented in handheld calculators to compute $\;\sqrt a$, whatever the initial value $u_0>0$. It converges *quadratically*, i.e. the number of exact digits doubles at each step.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(n) = f(n)-3$; we aim to show $g(n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. The recursion formula becomes
\begin{align*} g(n+1) + 3 &= \frac{1}{2}\left(g(n)+3+\frac{9}{g(n)+3}\right) \\\implies g(n+1) &= \frac{1}{2(g(n)+3)}\left((g(n)+3)^2-6(g(n)+3)+9\right) \\
&=\frac{g(n)^2}{2(g(n)+3)}. \end{align*}
We can make three conclusions from this:

1. Since $f(n)>0$, we know $g(n)+3>0$, and hence $g(n+1)\ge 0$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, i.e. $g$ is nonnegative except maybe for the first term.
2. If $g(n)$ is indeed nonnegative, then
   $$ g(n+1) = \frac{g(n)}{2(g(n)+3)}g(n) \le \frac{1}{2}g(n). $$
   This shows that $g$ decreases at least as fast as $\frac{1}{2^n}$, and hence tends to $0$.
3. For $g$ close to $0$, we have
   $$ g(n+1) = \frac{1}{2(g(n)+3)}g(n)^2 \approx \frac{1}{6}g(n)^2. $$
   If a small number is squared, then the number of leading zeros in its decimal expansion is doubled, hence explaining Bernard's remark that the sequence converges quadratically.

And, of course, all of this can be generalized to any numerator $a$ in the recursion, and not just $a=9$.